# Can I upgrade to iOS5 (beta) and still develop/debug against the current version of Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios5

As monotouch updates have stopped (another story), can I upgrade my iPhone/iPad to iOS 5 beta and still continue to develop using the current version of Monotouch?

I understand I wont have access to the new API's, but as its not possible to downgrade from iOS5, I was wondering has anyone else done the upgrade and it worked successfully?

I am currently in the middle of developing for iPhone using monotouch, so i want to be sure I dont make my only test devices incompatible, and essentially kill all my ability to develop using monotouch anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it still works - I just tried it - but beware of unexcepted behaviour from the APIs since the UIKit was heavily changed (styling features)

Also don't update the SDK just work with the current version - for debugging I can't vouch for it, because I'm in a very restricted WiFi at the moment (the app hung when trying to connect)

Regarding the downgrade - it's still possible according to various source (I did not try it) - you just have to place the phone into DFU Mode and make a recovery (your baseband won't downgrade!) - to be save just save the shsh with tinyUmbrella

Comment: Thanks for the info! I may hold off for the minute though. Hopefully  xamarin will have a release  around the GM release of ios5